# Go updates to go.mod needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Hi I want to work with Cobra in go for build a cli and I setup a workspace in vscode
that's my setting file

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      // Source code
      "name": "pcli",
      "path": "/home/andruxuis/Documents/Go/ProjectsSetup_CLI"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true
  },
}
```

I did generate a Cobra project with

```sh
    cobra init --pkg-name projectName
```

but I have the following Error in my go.mod file in the project root

> go [-e -json -compiled=true -test=true -export=false -deps=true
> -find=false -- builtin pcli/...]: exit status 1: go: updates to go.mod needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: @Flimzy I have fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code Go extension fails to load due to it being unable to change go.mod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141927/vs-code-go-extension-fails-to-load-due-to-it-being-unable-to-change-go-mod)