# VS Code Go extension fails to load due to it being unable to change go.mod?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

This question appears to have been asked in [Go updates to go.mod needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749886/go-updates-to-go-mod-needed-disabled-by-mod-readonly-packages-load-error) but was not answered there, so re-posting it. Running Go 1.15.7, I'm trying to load a Go project with a `go.mod` but VS Code is showing a notification with the following error:

```
Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.mod needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error
```

[image]

It seems that a read-only mode is enabled, but I'm not sure how to disable this. I've tried simply increasing the file permissions on `go.mod`,

```
chmod a+w go.mod
```

but to no avail. Any idea how to fix this error and allow the Go extension to load?

Comment: The error describes the reason, updating go.mod is disabled because of the `-mod=readonly` flag. Fix `go.mod` so the dependencies can be resolved.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "fix go.mod"? Shouldn't the extension itself be able to make the necessary updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error appears to have resolved itself by just running

```
go mod tidy
```

manually. I'm still curious what caused this, though, as the extension might still not be fully working.

Comment: running `go mod tidy` simply made the required changes to `go.mod`, which the plugin was not allowed to do because it is run with `-mod=readonly`

Comment: Ok, and how can I make it such that the plugin is allowed to make those changes and doesn't error out because of a `-mod=readonly` mode?

Comment: You would have to consult the documentation for that particular plugin. Normally you do not want plugins to silently make changes to your module configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily *fix* this by just adding to your `settings.json` a gopls build parameter allowing imports from out-of-scope modules.

Something along the lines of:

```json
{
    "gopls": {
    "build.allowModfileModifications": true
    }
}
```

For reference: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#buildallowmodfilemodifications

And a little more context:

> In Go 1.16, the Go command will no longer modify user's go.mod and go.sum files automatically (https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#tools). In order to match this behavior, gopls now also uses -mod=readonly when running the go command. Any errors reported by the go command will be presented with a suggested fix to make the necessary fixes to your go.mod or go.sum files. As a consequence, your workspace may be in a partially broken state while you have errors in your go.mod or go.sum file. golang/go#42266 will mitigate this, but it will likely not be resolved until February.

> Not recommended: If you must opt out of this behavior, you can set the allowModfileModifications configuration to true.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PROBLEMS section or the corresponding `go.mod` file. When such problems are detected, gopls provides quickfix and hints on how to address them there. If not, that's a bug.