# Go + VsCode: Git -> Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, go, visual-studio-code

My VSCode is having a difficult time with `Golang` and its updates with GitHub. On console, I can use `Git` normally, I also use `go` commands to build and run my `go` applications and everything works just fine. But, when I use `VSCode`, it simply cannot manage to authenticate via `SSH` the same way the console does.

The complete message is:

```
Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: github.com/abc/abc@v0.0.0-20210610172953-593247e413d4: 
invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in    
D:\Program Files\Go\bin\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\1c3dbe9a49296bf60aa851731c66574793ff0c41b2a50ff727de076b8a8fce2d: exit status 128: 
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. : packages.Load error
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Correct answer is on this post:
[VSCode, but show “Could not read from remote repository.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634364/to-use-git-push-on-visual-studio-code-but-show-could-not-read-from-remote-re/37882140)

Comment: Which one? Launching VSCode in an environment where ssh-agent has been activated? (only needed if your private key is passphrase-protected)

Comment: @VonC Yes, that actually worked for me.

Comment: OK. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check in a VSCode Terminal console (CMD) if you see any difference between:

- `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (again, from the CMD in VSCode)
- and `ssh -Tv git@github.com` from your regular CMD

There should be a difference in the path of the private keys considered for the connection, which should tell you why it does not work in VSCode (while it is working in your CMD)

A possible difference is, as pointed out by the OP with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882140/6309), the presence in the VSCode parent process environment, of [an ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).

If the private key is passphrase-protected, VSCode will need ssh-agent to read said key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, in both cases (in CMD in VSCode and on my regular CMD) I receive the same answer `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`. And the paths are the same also in both. Any other idea?

Comment: @JoeAlmore Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580058/6309